# How to get accounts/pages associated with a user using FbGraph2 gem?

Tags: ruby, fb-graph

I am using fb_graph2(1.1.1) in my rails project. My goal is to get all pages/accounts associated with a particular account. I am using this [document](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/fb_graph2) as a reference. And below is my code line which I wrote to get accounts. For some reason I am getting an error **"An unknown error has occurred."**

It would be great if someone can guide where and what am I doing wrong. Thanks!

```
FbGraph2::User.me(<ACCESS_TOKEN>).accounts
```